# Can we mirror SQL Server tables from one DB into another with acceptable performance?

Tags: sql-server, performance, mirror

We have two servers, A and B

on server A we have DB OPS_001 with a number of tables.

on server B we have DB XYZ with a number of tables.

We consider a project of integrating both systems and start pointing the resulting system to the tables in server B (for foreign keys/etc). We face some technical difficulties physically moving all tables from server A.OPS_001 into B.XYZ due to legacy applications that need to have connections rewritten and compiled.

Is there a way to mirror server A.OPS_001 tables in B.XYZ such a way that the performance is still acceptable (like not taking 1,2 seconds for a select on a PK)? I know acceptable is a very generic term but take in consideration around 150 users rely on those 2 databases from 9am to 5pm.

I've tested linked server views but it's very slow.

Just so you know, A is a SQL Server 2000 and B is SQL Server 2008.

EDIT:

Size of the source DB is 220 tables and the file itself around 14 GB.

Comment: What is "acceptable" to you?? How many tables, how many GB of data are we talking about??

Comment: acceptable would be a 10% decrease in performance overall lets say. I don't know what acceptable is exactly. We're talking about around 220 tables, 14 GB of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to migrate the database to the same server and since the databases were extremely tightly coupled, they should be merged together and form a single database with relational integrity.